# Asp.net core Razor Radio button not passing desired values to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a problem with my form its not passing radio button selected value to controller but another values are passed successfully when debugging.
Please note Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed its boolean, I noticed the this Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed passed through the form at all.
What am I missing on the radio button:
Here is my form and controller, your assistance will be greatly appreciated:

```
<form asp-action="Review">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Job.Id" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p><strong>Approve or Reject public submission</strong></p>
                        <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-radio-input" name="status" value="True" type="radio" asp-for="Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed" /> Approve
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" name="status" value="False" type="radio" asp-for="Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed" /> Reject
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row showapprove" id="True">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="Job.JobCategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                            <select asp-for="Job.JobCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.JobCategoryId">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="Job.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Job.Name" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Job.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="Job.JobNo" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Job.JobNo" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Job.JobNo" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label asp-for="Job.ContractorId" class="control-label"></label>
                            <select asp-for="Job.ContractorId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ContractorId">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>





public async Task<IActionResult> Review(int id, JobViewModel model)
    {
        if (id != model.Job.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var job = _context.Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

                if (model.Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed == true) // approve public submission
                {
                    job.PublicSubmissionReviewed = true;
                    job.PublicSubmissionReviewDate = DateTime.Now;
                    job.Name = model.Job.Name;
                    job.New = true;
                    job.JobNo = model.Job.JobNo;
                    job.JobCategoryId = model.Job.JobCategoryId;
                    job.ContractorId = model.Job.ContractorId;
                    _context.Update(job);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Public));
                }
                else if (model.Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed == false) // reject public submission
                {
                    job.PublicSubmissionReviewed = true;
                    job.PublicSubmissionReviewDate = DateTime.Now;
                    job.New = false;
                    job.PublicSubmissionRejected = true;
                    job.PublicSubmissionRejectedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    job.PublicSubmissionReviewRejectReason = model.Job.PublicSubmissionReviewRejectReason;

                    _context.Update(job);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Public));
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!JobExists(model.Job.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` HTML attribute in a form element is what will be sent to the server to identify that field once you submit the form. Razor's model binding expects a certain name for form fields, and `asp-for` automatically sets that name for you. Since you've manually specified a name instead, the model binder will not be able to recognize the field, and therefore will not set it in your model.

It looks like you're setting the name in order to group the radio buttons together. Since `asp-for` will use the same name for a given bound property, you do not need to worry about that; all radio buttons corresponding to a certain property will be grouped together.

Therefore, you can simply remove the `name` attribute and your code should then work fine:

```html
<input class="form-radio-input" value="True" type="radio" asp-for="Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed" /> Approve
```

```html
<input class="form-check-input" value="False" type="radio" asp-for="Job.PublicSubmissionReviewed" /> Reject
```